# How to increment by 1 a loop in Visual Basic for Application

Tags: excel, vba

My first question on Stackoverflow, and a newbe, so please bare with me.

I am trying to sort out an excel sheet with 411,278 rows, about stock market data.

My code is as follows:

```
    Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
        Range("C6:C1577").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("D5").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
             False, Transpose:=True
        Range("B6:C1577").Select
        Range("C6").Activate
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

I am trying to insert the above code in a loop that will increment all the numbers within the loop by 1.

For example (the next phase in the loop will be):

```
    Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
            Range("C7:C1578").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("D6").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
                 False, Transpose:=True
            Range("B7:C1578").Select
            Range("C7").Activate
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you select `B6:C1577` and delete it then you want to copy `C7:C1578` on the next loop even though most of it will be empty because you just deleted all but `C1578`? Better option here is just to `Clear` rather than `Delete` as clearing will be easier as it doesn't interfere with the looping.

Comment: You are copying `1572` cells. Before deleting, cells `C5, C1578, C3151...` are of some significance since the latter two will be shifted to cells `... C6, C7...` while deleting. Is that true? What is the connection to the `411,278` rows? `411,278` divided by `1572` or by `1573` is not a whole number. Please do clarify.

Comment: @VBasic2008 there's no dividing, he wants to loop 1 by 1 all the way to that number. Basically from what I gather he's asking for a loop of `For i = 1577 to 411278`

Comment: @Simon: You should try the code. You probably did not notice that when the cells (range) are deleted the whole data below will shift up 1572 cells. If you do this roughly 262 times your out of data.

Comment: Thats why I said in my first comment to Clear rather than Delete but we will see when the OP comments.

Comment: Hi, my intentions are as mentioned by VBasic2008 is to do this 262 times until I am out of data. Basically the code copy the 1,573 cells that are +1 from the last iteration of the loop, then transpose them, then deleting C & B (also 1,573 cells) and continue with the loop.

Comment: The function `.Offset()` moves the reference down or across by a certain amount. Like `Range("A2").Offset(1,0)` points to `[A3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not try this code without taking precautions.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim Rng             As Range
    Dim Rstart          As Long         ' start of range row
    Dim Rend            As Long         ' end of range row
    Dim Target          As Range        ' destination of copy action
    Dim DelRng          As Range        ' range to delete
    
    Rstart = 6
    Rend = 1577
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(Rstart, "C"), Cells(Rend, "C"))
        Set Target = Cells(Rstart - 1, "D")
        Set DelRng = Range(Cells(Rstart, "B"), Cells(Rend, "C"))
        Rng.Copy
        TargetPasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
                           Operation:=xlNone, _
                           SkipBlanks:=False, _
                           Transpose:=True
        DelRng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rstart = Rstart + 1
    Loop Until Rstart = Rend
    
    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Primary precaution to take is to understand the code. Start and End rows are specified at the top. They are used to set 3 ranges in columns C, D and B:C. Initially, they are precisely your 3 ranges Range("C6:C1577"), Range("D5"), Range("B6:C1577"). The code copies from the first range to the second and then deletes the third. It does so without selecting anything because once VBA is told where a range is it doesn't need to select it.

You will notice that there is no equivalent of your `Range("C7").Activate`. That's because C7 is within the range Range("B6:C1577") which is earmarked for destruction. It makes no difference which cell in it is active. However, I have some doubt about the deletion and whether you actually meant to delete only this cell (which your code doesn't do). Please check my code against your intentions in this regard.

Now the critical part. That's the loop. On each iteration the 3 ranges are moved one row down. The line of code requiring your attention is this one.

```
Loop Until Rng.Row = Rend
```

The loop will continue until the first row of the first range is equal to `Rend`. That means that there will be 1571 loops - probably enough time to have a coffee and a chat even while screen updating is turned off. But even this fearsome number is definitely wrong. Your question gives no clue as to your needs but I guess it should be like `Loop Until Rng.Row = (411278 - Rend)`, give or take 1. I didn't want to enter into an argument about this final, last row (which tends to be omitted in loops) while not believing that your number of rows is invariable. I think it should be replaced with a formula that finds the last existing row in a particular column.

However, your question was how to advance the ranges. My code does that beautifully. Enjoy the show.

Comment: Hi Variatus, Thanks a lot for this! I met an error in Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1) runtime error object required, after doing one iteration and moving the values + deleting them. You were right about the intention for deleting both on B and C

Comment: Hello Oris, Sorry about the delay and the error. I was without Internet for 2 days. The error was a logical one: after `Rng` is deleted it can't be modified anymore. In the revised code I published the range is recreated on each loop instead of being moved.

Comment: Thanks! I will run some tests and will update you on the results. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### A Data Transpose

- The following will copy only the values (no formatting or formulas).
- Adjust the values in the constants section. Note that you can choose a different worksheet for the result to leave your source data intact.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub transposeValues()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcColumns As String = "B:D"
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 5
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstFirstCell As String = "B5"
    Const dCount As Long = 1573
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(srcName).Columns(srcColumns)
        Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - srcFirstRow + 1) _
            .Offset(srcFirstRow - 1).Find( _
                What:="*", _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rng = .Resize(rng.Row - srcFirstRow + 1).Offset(srcFirstRow - 1)
    End With
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rng.Value
    
    ' Define Result Array.
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(Data)
    Dim Remainder As Long: Remainder = srCount Mod dCount
    Dim drCount As Long
    If Remainder = 0 Then
        drCount = srCount / dCount
    Else
        drCount = Int(srCount / dCount) + 1
    End If
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = dCount + 1
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    ' Declare counters.
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Result Array.
    If drCount = 1 And Remainder > 0 Then
        i = 1
    Else
        For i = 1 To drCount + (Remainder <> 0) * 1 ' In VBA 'True = -1'.
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To 2
                Result(i, j) = Data(k, j)
            Next j
            For j = 3 To dcCount
                k = k + 1
                Result(i, j) = Data(k, 2)
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
    
    ' Write the remainder of values in Data Array to Result Array.
    If Remainder > 0 Then
        k = k + 1
        For j = 1 To 2
            Result(i, j) = Data(k, j)
        Next j
        If Remainder > 1 Then
            For j = 3 To 1 + Remainder
                k = k + 1
                Result(i, j) = Data(k, 2)
            Next j
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Result Array to Destination Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dstFirstCell).Resize(, dcCount)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(drCount).Value = Result
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Vbasic2008, Thanks a lot for this. I will need to run few test and I'll report back.